# Postgres use multiple tablespaces in a single database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, tablespaces

Is it possible to allocate tables directly to tablespaces within a single database/schema in postgres? Based on the docs, tablespace is a `create database` argument, but are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-TABLESPACE) you can specify a tablespace when creating a table.

However, tablespaces are rarely used in Postgres as they don't really provide any advantage.

One of the few reasons to use them is, when you can't easily expand the size of your filesystem where the data directory is located.

Comment: thanks, I missed that part... actually I wanted to put some tables on a ramdisk, but not all of them, for experimental reasons

Comment: `However, tablespaces are rarely used in Postgres as they don't really provide any advantage.` - why not? What if you wanted to put two heavily used tables on different disks and you didn't have a RAID 10 setup? I presume [SAME](http://www.orafaq.com/maillist/oracle-l/2001/01/12/0576.htm) is recommended for top-tier deployments?

Comment: @Vérace: that is another one of the few reasons. But most people tend to use multiple disks in a RAID configuration these days.

Comment: @Vérace  You can use tablespaces for that, but for any single query you will probably not have simultaneous outstanding read requests for both tables, so it probably wouldn't be effective unless you have high session concurrency.  But why would you not have a RAID (or something equivalent) setup?  That is not very far away from asking "what if I want to run PostgreSQL on a stack of punch cards".  I don't think you need to be top-tier to use SAME anymore.  I mean, I don't have it on my laptop, but I also don't have multiple hard drives.